# Restart from the beginning of the array if you have reached the end of it in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, encryption

my goal is to replace the characters of a sentence with those found in a certain number of positions (provided in input) later in the alphabet. A kind of encryption.
My problem is if in the sentence there is a Z or some character that exceeds the maximum size of the array. How can I make sure that if someone (for example) writes Y and moves it by 3 characters, the value will be B?

```
function criptaFrase(){
var alfabeto = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
var frase = document.getElementById("frase").value;
var scambia = "";
var posti = parseInt(document.getElementById("posti").value);

for (a = 0; a < frase.length; a++) {
    let b = alfabeto.indexOf(frase.charAt(a));
    b += posti;
    scambia += alfabeto[b];
    document.getElementById("finale").innerHTML = scambia;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap around anything that's indexed starting at 0 by using the remainder operator (`%`) and the length of the thing.

So if it's `b += posti;` you're talking about, that would be:

```
b = (b + posti) % alfabeto.length;
```

Here's an isolated example of that wrap-around:

```js
const list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
let i = 0;
for (let counter = 0; counter < 12; ++counter) {
    console.log(`${i}: ${list[i]}`);
    i = (i + 1) % list.length;
}
```

---

*(If you have someting indexed starting with 1, you can do the same thing like this: `x = x % length + 1;`. But JavaScript array indexes start at 0.)*

Comment: how do you reset it to the last element of the array when index reaches 0 if you are decrementing it and not increasing it.